# Better SQL to link records within 1 hour sliding window

Tags: hive, count, hbase, aggregate-functions, sliding-window

I try to create a new table with (user1, user2, count), denoting the number of time both users share same value in one column within 1 hour interval.

```
WITH d1 AS (SELECT * FROM user_access_tab 
WHERE last_access >= 1544630400 AND last_access <= 1545601214)
SELECT d1.userid, d2.userid, COUNT(*) as count
FROM d1
INNER JOIN d1 AS d2
ON d1.item = d2.item AND d1.userid != d2.userid
WHERE d1.last_access < d2.last_access  AND 
      (d2.last_access - d1.last_access) <= 3600
GROUP BY d1.userid, d2.userid
```

However, such queries are very slow even with just 1 hour interval limit. I need to query about 6 months data, which accumulated to billions rows of records. How can I improve the SQL ?

The user_access_tab looks like below

[image: user_access_tab]

The new table looks like below. Two userids are linked as long as their last_access are within 1 hour window, and counter increases by 1.

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, describe the logic you want to implement -- sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Does `last_access` have any index on it..?

Comment: Let's say user 24830131 gets access to item A between the 2 records you have shared. What would be the expected result? (I am asking because your expectations may increase the number of records returned tremendously).

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan no, it doesn't.

Comment: @lau, you're right. Let say user 24830131 get access to item A with user 52539489 within same hour, a new row . (24830131, 52539489, 1) will be generated. However, I'm thinking to add a threshold HAVING COUNT(*) > 100  for eg to limit the number of returning row. To make the question simple, I just leave it as it is

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the problem with your query is that you join way too many records with each others.

Take the minimal example below where I inserted a CTE:

```
WITH user_access_tab(item, userid, last_access) AS (
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']), 
           UNNEST(ARRAY[11383575,11383575,52539489,52539489,24830131,24830131]),
           UNNEST(ARRAY[1545645324,1545645325,1545647895,1545647896,1545646895,1545646896])
    /*UNION ALL
    SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']), 
           UNNEST(ARRAY[11383575,11383575,52539489,52539489,24830131,24830131]),
           UNNEST(ARRAY[1545645326,1545645327,1545647897,1545647898,1545646897,1545646898])*/
),
d1 AS (SELECT * FROM user_access_tab 
WHERE last_access >= 1544630400 AND last_access <= 1545661214
)                       
SELECT d1.userid, d2.userid, COUNT(*) as count
FROM d1
INNER JOIN d1 AS d2
ON d1.item = d2.item AND d1.userid != d2.userid
WHERE d1.last_access < d2.last_access  AND 
      (d2.last_access - d1.last_access) <= 3600
GROUP BY d1.userid, d2.userid
```

The CTE has 6 records and the query returns 3 records with a count equal to 4 for each.
Now uncomment the second half of the CTE and what you get is 3x16. That is more than the number of records in the CTE and it only gets worse with more users and events.

I would suggest you do something WAY more restrictive on 1 side of your `JOIN`. Example below:

```
WITH d1 AS (SELECT * FROM user_access_tab 
WHERE last_access >= 1544630400 AND last_access <= 1545661214),
d2 AS (
SELECT *
FROM d1 d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM d1 WHERE item = d.item AND userid = d.userid AND d.last_access BETWEEN last_access+1 AND d.last_access + 3600))
SELECT d2.item, d2.userid, d1.userid, COUNT(*)
FROM d2
LEFT OUTER JOIN d1 ON d2.item = d1.item AND d2.userid = d1.userid AND d1.last_access BETWEEN d2.last_access and d2.last_access + 3600
GROUP BY d2.item, d2.userid, d1.userid
```

Obviously, this will change the result in the `COUNT(*)` column (on top of being faster) but since it did not seem to make much sense before, I would say it is for the best.